# how can I know that a method was applied? checking getattr() is not providing any clear clue

Tags: python, methods, scikit-learn, attributes, knn

Suppose I am trying to fit a K-nearest neighbors classifier:

```
***from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = 1)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)***
```

The X_train here is some pandas.DataFrame with double-type values while the y_train is a pandas.Series with double-type as well.

How can I know the last command line was indeed executed? In other words, is there any place where something referring to the use of method '.fit' was stored? I tried using 'getattr()', but ended up retrieving the same result whether or not executing the fitting command line.

Your help is pretty much appreciated!

Comment: Print or log something before and after that line?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  If the code executes as shown, then the `.fit()` method will certainly be called.  Are you saying this entire code block might be behind an `if` statement, which might be false?

Comment: I would do what @wwii suggested. Below each line you want to observe, you can print a message indicating that the previous line was executed.

Comment: My apologies if my question was not clear.
What I need to know is where inside knn is knn.fit action stored and how can I access it. 

If I try:
getattr(knn,'fit') 
I will get:
<bound method KNeighborsClassifier.fit of KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)>
but I would retrieve the same output if I did not run the knn.fit command line. 
If I try to run knn.predict(pandas.Series(aseries)) after running the .fit this will work. If I do not run the .fit this will not work. That means the '.fit' action was stored somewhere.